# Accessing Travis Secure Environment Variables Node.js/PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

I have a database uri that I wanted to secure in my travis yml file. I followed the travis docs to encrypt the following environment variable:     PROD_DB_URI = MY_DB_URI

I then replaced the URI in my actual database file with this new environment variable that I expect to have access to.

Here is where I added it:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
let privateKey;
if (process.env.PROD_DB_URI) {
 privateKey = process.env.PROD_DB_URI;
} else {
 privateKey = require('./../../testingKeys.js').dbKey;
}
const DB = new Sequelize(privateKey);
```

My travis yml file looks like this:

```
language: node_js
 node_js:
 - '4'
 env:
   global:
   - CXX=g++-4.8
   - secure: s6/R8v6Nxe8Vw0gnge+0/...
 addons:
   apt:
     sources:
     - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
     packages:
     - g++-4.8
 after_success: npm run coverage
```

I tried running travis and it is unable to see the encrypted PROD_DB_URI variable and says its undefined. I even looked at the travis logs and when it exports environment variables it doesn't show the decrypted variable. The logs show:

```
Setting environment variables from .travis.yml

$ export CXX=g++-4.8
```

No other variables are being exported. I have also checked to see if the process.env.TRAVIS_SECURE_ENV_VARS was returning true, and it was.

I also saw in the travis docs that you can also add environment variables in their dashboard. I added the key, value pair in the dashboard as PROD_DB_URI = MY_DB_URI. Travis again says its undefined.

Is there something that I am missing? Am I not accessing the secure environment variables properly?

Comment: Also have this issue. Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

For more refer [this link](https://blog.cloudboost.io/managing-node-environment-when-testing-on-travis-and-locally-7026dec47eb2).

---

In your `.travis.yml` file add:

```
env:
- PROD_DB_URI=$PROD_DB_URI
```

> `PROD_DB_URI` should be set as environment variable in travis

Comment: this worked for me and should be the accepted answer, thanks!